# Django aggregation: Group and sum over a date range

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-aggregation

I am fetching some user stats daily and recording them in a model as follows (irrelevant parts are stripped off for simplicity):

```
class User(models.Model):
    group = models.CharField(
        choices=(('A', 'Group A'), ('B', 'Group B'),
    ))

class Stats(models.Model):
    day = models.DateField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    follower_count = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

As seen above, each user belongs to a group.

How can I get the sum each user's `follower_count`s for each **group** over a date range?

In other words, what is the best way to build a data structure as follows using these models? Is it possible to do it with a single aggregate query?

```
[{
    'date': '2015-07-15',
    'Group A': 26,  # sum of followers of users in Group A on 2015-07-15
    'Group B': 15,
 }, {
    'date': '2015-07-16',
    'Group A': 30, 
    'Group B': 18,
 }, {
    'date': '2015-07-17',
    'Group A': 32, 
    'Group B': 25,
 }]
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to get the desired aggregate query by using this block of code.

```
Stats.objects.values('day').annotate(
    group_a=Sum(Case(When(user__group='A', then='follower_count'))),
    group_b=Sum(Case(When(user__group='B', then='follower_count')))
)
```

Basically it tells the Django ORM to get the sums of the follower_count's of the two groups A and B, and the column aliases will be "group_a" and "group_b" respectively. The aggregation will be performed with a GROUP BY using the 'day' field.

The resulting queryset will give you the details you want. The rest will be just formatting. You may use the basic [JSON serializer Django provides](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/serialization/#serialization-formats-json) to get the format you want, but if it is for a Web API, you might want to take a look at [Django REST Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/), particularly the serializers.

Comment: Thanks, great. I didn't know about this new conditional expressions that come with Django 1.8.